# Can you change the windows boot loading animation on windows 10?

Tags: boot

Just out of curiosity, can you change the loading animation on boot on Windows 10? I know how to access the `EFI` partition with read-write. Is there a specific `dll` I should edit?
I'm on a `UEFI` system.

Comment: [Metabolix/HackBGRT: Windows boot logo changer for UEFI systems](https://github.com/Metabolix/HackBGRT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article here](https://technastic.com/how-to-change-uefi-boot-logo-from-windows/) shows you can with a 24bit BMP, and Secure Boot Disabled. Please make sure you have a backup and/or a restore point made as this can make you Windows install unbootable. Also note I couldn't find any info on how to change the animation, only the logo.